# TotalHours function error handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes for each day of the week which allow a user to enter a start time and an end time in this format (hh:mm) (24 hour clock). For example, if a user enters 1:35 in the first textbox for Monday and 3:30 in the second textbox for Monday and press the 'Calculate' button, it will return the decimal 1.92. It runs and returns the result to a label, but I'm having some problems with my error handling.

If a textbox is left empty it will throw an error when ran and display "String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan." How can I fix this so if a user doesn't enter a time it will either assume '0' or not run the code with that particular set of empty textboxes?

```
//Monday
TimeSpan Mon1In = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxInMon1.Text);
TimeSpan Mon1Out = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxOutMon1.Text);
MonLabel1.Text = (Mon1Out - Mon1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");

//Tuesday
TimeSpan Tues1In = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxInTues1.Text);
TimeSpan Tues1Out = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxOutTues1.Text);
TuesLabel1.Text = (Tues1Out - Tues1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");

//Wednesday
TimeSpan Wed1In = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxInWed1.Text);
TimeSpan Wed1Out = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxOutWed1.Text);
WedLabel1.Text = (Wed1Out - Wed1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
```

all the way to Friday.

Comment: Use `TryPArse` instead of `Parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`TimeSpan.TryParse`<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the out param is the value you would like and if the tryparse fails you set the TimeSpan to 00:00:00.

```
//Monday
TimeSpan Mon1In,Mon1Out;
if(!TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBoxInMon1.Text,out Mon1In)) Mon1In = default(TimeSpan);
if(!TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBoxOutMon1.Text,out Mon1Out)) Mon1Out = default(TimeSpan);
MonLabel1.Text = (Mon1Out - Mon1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
```